# Play Video From Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

recently I have see that one of my apps feature stopped working. The main problem is that, now, I can play instagram videos from an URL. This feature was working time ago, but I can not say how time is broken because I have noticed the problem now.

For example, I have this URL from Instagram:

```
https://embed.storiesig.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
```

If you open the URL in web browser (Safari, Chrome, etc...) you will see the video running.

But If I try to play the video from a AVPlayer like it used to work, the video is not played. My code for video playback is like this:

```
let videoUrl = story.videoUrl!
if (videoUrl.absoluteString.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8) > 0) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

Where `story.videoUrl` is the URL of the example. If yo play the URL in a AVPlayer you will see nothing, so I don't know what is going on.